# Disable/enable jsp page upon selection of a checkbox

Tags: jsp, events, spring-webflow

I have a check box in some jsp page...if the check box is selected, abc.jsp will trigger...if it is not selected xyz.jsp should trigger...can anyone help me in achieving this...I want to have code lines in jsp itself...

this is what I have in one of my class file

```
private boolean useNis = false;

public boolean isUseNis() {
return useNis;
    }

public void setUseNis(boolean useNis) {
this.useNis = useNis;
    }
```

in my hbm.xml file, the following is the only line I have

```
<property name="useNis" type="yes_no" column="USENIS" not-null="true"/>
```

In abc.jsp, i have this code

```
<form:checkbox path="useNis"/>
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="_useNis"/>
```

In xyz.jsp, I have these lines

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${Location.useNis==true}">
<button type="submit" name="_eventId_searchLoadKeys"><fmt:message key="SEARCH" /></button> 
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<button type="submit" name="_eventId_searchNisLoadKeys"><fmt:message key="SEARCH" /></button>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

`<c:when test="${Location.useNis==true}">` ...this line in xyz.jsp should check for the checkbox selected or not!!! if that is solved I will get what I want..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the checkbox is changed on the client side, the only way you could have the logic entirely in that first JSP is with client-side code. i.e. JavaScript.

The "WebFlow" way to do this instead is to have the checkbox bind to a model attribute, and use a `decision-state` or `action-state` in your flow configuration file to check the value of that attribute in order to decide which of the two JSP `view-state`s to transition to next.

Example of the flow.xml portions:

```
<var name="checkboxForm" class="package.CheckboxFormBean"/>

<view-state id="start" view="start.jsp" model="checkboxForm">
    <transition on="submit" to="checkCheckbox"/>
</view-state>

<decision-state id="checkCheckbox">
    <if test="checkboxForm.checked" then="abc" else="xyz"/>
</decision-state>

<view-state id="abc" view="abc.jsp"/>

<view-state id="xyz" view="xyz.jsp"/>
```

Where your `package.CheckboxFormBean` class will have a `boolean isChecked()` method.